# ExtJS Grid Scrollbar jumps in ie8

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 4.0.2 and there seems to be a bug, and I haven't found a clear solution to it.
I have a container with anchor layout, which contains some elements and a grid. When the window is re-sized so the grid doesn't fit anymore, the scrollbar appears on the container which is correct. However if I scroll down to the end, and select an item in the grid, the scroll jumps to the middle. This problem appears only in IE 8. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behavior in IE8 is affected alot by any custom css used. Are you using any CSS file other then extjs too? Try by removing it once and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I read about a month ago that someone wanted to scroll to the same position after destroying and rendering the grid. The solution to that idea was to assign the scrolled pixels in a var, then after rendering, set the scroll to the same pixels (there is a function scrollTo();). So you could do the same thing, when you click and it scrolls to top, force it to scroll the same position. It's a stupid solution but.. just in case you can't fix it.